# Allure Framework with Jenkins - is there a way to see progression over multiple builds?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

I have gotten Allure working in Jenkins and can see the reports it produces for each build. Is there a way to 'zoom out' so we can see how we are progressing, build to build? I.e. in this build, we had 7 failures, but the next build, we had only 5, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AFAIK Allure (Jenkins plugin) doesn't support history tracking. Please use Sonar Qube or similar tools for it.

Allure is very lightweight static report. There is demand for Allure Server which were able to store all the reports (aggregate and compare statistics, finding flaky tests, monitoring current execution in real time, etc.), but currently it is not implemented.

Comment: Do you mind naming some of the other tools that are similar to Sonar Qube? Thanks.